# when call one method from one controller to another controller session becomes null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

when calling a method from controller to another controller then session becomes null

```
HRPayGenerateController pay = new HRPayGenerateController(_paygenerateService);

Guid[] tabledata = new Guid[1];
tabledata[0]= hrPayGenarate.Id;


_HRPayGenerate.Pay(tabledata);

public dynamic Pay(Guid[] TableData)
{ 
    Guid BusinessUnitId = Guid.Parse(Session["BusinessUnitId"].ToString());
}
```

the above line shows null error

Comment: Where are you setting `Session["BusinessUnitId"]` value?

Comment: why do you need to call another controller like this? It is not good practice.

Comment: Recommend you replace your model-view-controller (a design pattern) tag with asp.net-mvc (specific technology you're asking about) - possibly also a versioned tag like asp.net-mvc-5

Comment: The posted code does not show an Action calling another Action. Details matter. Read the [mcve] page.

Answer (score 0):

The session is populated by the request pipeline of the aspnet. 
Because you call the controller manually, which is something you should avoid at all times because controllers are made to process requests and not meant to be called manually since that breaks the whole request pipeline.

Since the session is set somewhere on the request pipeline and you are calling the controller manually none of those variables will be available inside that controller, but they will be on the controller that you are calling it from, since that is part of the request pipeline. Maybe you can access it from that and pass it in as parameter.

**The best option is to user a service to do the payment or whatever is inside the pay action, and use that service in both controllers.**